# How to select multiple vertices in order?

Tags: vertices, edges, selection-tools

I can manually select multiple vertices in order and press <kbd>J</kbd> to connect them with edges.

[image]

But I don't want to manually select vertices. I need whatever [selection method](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html) available to select them in order. Is that even possible? Or else I would get the error `Invalid Selection Order`. It's funny because in this example it should have selected the vertices in order:

[image]

Ultimately I would need it to work with the Lasso Tool. I know I can create a circle with edges but take note that this is just a simple example and I would eventually have different shapes.

[image]

Comment: and how should blender now what order you mean?

Comment: blender should know in at least the 2nd gif using `C`. notice how i select them in order :)

Comment: I agree with that 

Comment: I could see how Blender would decide the order when you are using _Circle Select_ or the _Lasso Select_ tool... since you already found out it doesn't work this might be qualifying for a feature request on [Blender Right-Click Select?](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot)

Comment: Can you give one of your  real, more complex use-cases?

Comment: @RobinBetts i didn't want to do this one manually https://i.stack.imgur.com/24X6n.gif i was hoping i could highlight all the vertices in x-ray mode at once and split the edges with `j` but that even didn't work with manual selection so i ended up selecting directly with the knife tool.

Comment: @Harry Ahh, OK, that's a cut as well as edge-creation..maybe an _Intersect Knife_ ... but I agree it would be nice to have an operator that filled edges as you brushed over vertices..must be writeable as an add-on, surely?